# Spring boot failsafe integration tests - Failed to find merged annotation after upgrade to 2.4.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, maven-failsafe-plugin

after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.4.2 (Spring 5.3.3) our Spring Context tests broke:

```
lut 15, 2021 4:37:49 PM org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.JupiterEngineExecutionContext close
SEVERE: Caught exception while closing extension context: org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterEngineExtensionContext@27be17c8
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find merged annotation for @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextAnnotationUtils$AnnotationDescriptor.<init>(TestContextAnnotationUtils.java:513)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptor(TestContextAnnotationUtils.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptor(TestContextAnnotationUtils.java:214)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveExplicitTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$4(ExtensionValuesStore.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:205)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.evaluate(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.access$100(ExtensionValuesStore.java:171)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$closeAllStoredCloseableValues$1(ExtensionValuesStore.java:65)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:176)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ConcurrentHashMap.java:3612)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.closeAllStoredCloseableValues(ExtensionValuesStore.java:68)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.AbstractExtensionContext.close(AbstractExtensionContext.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.JupiterEngineExecutionContext.close(JupiterEngineExecutionContext.java:53)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterEngineDescriptor.cleanUp(JupiterEngineDescriptor.java:67)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterEngineDescriptor.cleanUp(JupiterEngineDescriptor.java:29)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$cleanUp$9(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.cleanUp(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:87)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:428)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:562)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:548)
```

I've already upgraded Surefire and Failsafe maven plugins to 3.0.0-M5, but without any improvement. Junit Jupiter is at 5.7.0.

There are no dependency version conflicts between Spring, Spring Boot and Spring Tests. Issue only occurs for failsafe `integration-test` goal.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't use spring-boot-starter-parent as a parent of your maven project, then you need to manually inform the Failsafe plugin which class directory to use by adding this configuration to the Failsafe plugin section in pom.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
</configuration>
```

Source: [Comment on the Apache issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1198?focusedCommentId=16674086&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16674086)

Answer (score 0):

The Surefire plugin uses `target/classes`.
The Failsafe plugin uses `target/your.jar` and so therefore you may see the difference. The Spring builds the fat JAR and therefore you should always consider this difference between plugins. The Failsafe plugin adds dependencies to the classpath and the `target/your.jar` is not considered a fat JAR by the plugin. It is supposed to be a normal package of project classes.